# NumPy (python)matrix column copying isn't working

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I'm currently learning python and numpy and I'm testing this code because I can't get `A[:, 1] = arr[:, 0]` to work whatsoever. I thought it was maybe an object thing or something (coming from javascript/java/C to python) but it seems it's actually the `arr[:, 0]` that is causing issues saying that there is too many indices... but I'm just printing all of the indices in column 1 right? Lost Here.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
degree = 7
A = np.ones((len(arr), degree))
print(A[:, 1])
print(arr[:, 0])
```

^ full attached code above

Comment: What is the expected output? `arr` is one dimensional so you can't give it two dimensional indices.

Answer (score 1):

For a numpy array, the number of indices cannot exceed the number of dimensions. Thus for a 1D array, giving two indices (`:, 0` is two indices) is invalid, which is why you observe this error for `arr` but not for `A`.

`arr[0]` would give you the first element of `arr`, or just `arr` gives you the entire array.